# Google Analytics v4 Cast Error in my android app

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

EDIT: I fixed error. But still I can not see real time visitors on Google Analytics window. I check three times my tracking id. It is correct, there is no error in code. But why I cant stil my visitors? Min 1 visitor should be in real time visitor area. Because i'm on my app.

I want to use google analytics v4 for my application. I add a class [**according**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to google doc.

**GoogleAnal.java**

```
public class GoogleAnal extends Application {
    public GoogleAnal() {
        super();
        }
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();


    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            if(trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER){
                Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
            }         
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
....
....
....
//Below line gives Error: 
//11-26 09:52:35.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2239): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxx.helloworld.GoogleAnal

((GoogleAnal) getApplication()).getTracker(GoogleAnal.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
```

Where I'm doing wrong? What should I write instead of `((GoogleAnal) getApplication()).getTracker(GoogleAnal.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);`

If my way is all wrong, can you give some suggestions?

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 2):

OPTION 1: Have you added GoogleAnal in your manifest??

```
<application
    android:name="com.xxx.helloworld.GoogleAnal"
    ...
```

OPTION 2: this is my getTracker method inside my Application:

```
synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {

    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
        t.setAppName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        t.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
        t.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

Comment: @hakiko it seems like the problem is not related with Google Analytics. The error seems to indicate that GoogleAnal cannot be casted to Application. Try calling ((GoogleAnal) getApplication()) to know if your problem is related with Analytics or not.

Comment: I fixed errors, app opening normally but on analytics' real time window there is no action. Still "0" visitor

Comment: real time is not real time indeed. It will take a time to update the results.

Comment: Real time it is not real time but latency is about 15 seconds. I'm waiting about 2 hours

Comment: @hakiko I've waited longer periods to see my applications on Google Analytics. I really don't know if you are implementing fine the process, but you should wait more.